# Continuous invariants of singularities in the Thom-Mather theory of deformations

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, singularity-theory

I have been reading through Arnold et al.'s [*Singularities of differentiable maps*](https://www.google.es/books/edition/Singularities_of_Differentiable_Maps/25bwBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) to have an understanding on Arnold's theory of deformations of wave fronts. His theory is similar to the Thom-Mather theory of deformations of smooth maps, only that it has been adapted to the space of wave fronts $\mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$.

In Section 21.8, the authors outline the classification of generic wave fronts up to dimension 10. The main points related to my question are as follows:

- if $n \geq 6$, the germs of generic wave fronts are unstable at certain points and have moduli;
- *the number of moduli remains finite* up to $n = 9$, and becomes functional for $n \geq 10$.

Earlier in the book (Section 1.10), the authors explain Mather's notion of *nice dimensions*, and touch on the idea of *moduli*. Their explanation is brief, however, and I do not quite grasp what they mean by "continuous invariants of singularities":

> For example, the stable maps are not dense in the space of [$\mathbb{C}^9 \to \mathbb{C}^9$] maps and there is not a finite list of singularities of generic maps. The classes of differentiable equivalence of singularities of generic maps do not form a discrete set but a continuous set (there are continuous invariants of singularities, the so-called *moduli*).

My question is, could someone give me some directions so I can wrap my head around these "finite" and "functional" moduli? Just having some pointers would go a long way, such as a reference where I can read a bit more about these continuous invariants.

Thank you!